# Database functional dependencies

Tags: mysql, database, dependencies

Im trying to find some functional dependencies  in my database but have no idea how to do it. Would anyone be able to explain how to do it or what the functional dependencies  are . Heres my code for creating my tables

```
CREATE TABLE   Customer(
      CustomerID     int  PRIMARY KEY,
      CustomerName   varchar(50)  NOT NULL,
      BillingAddress varchar(400)  default NULL,
      PhoneNumber    varchar(128)  NOT NULL,
      UserEmail     varchar(128) UNIQUE
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OrderMaster(
      OrderID             int NOT NULL  PRIMARY KEY,
      CustomerID          int,
      OrderDate           date  NOT NULL,
      PurchaseOrderNumber int
 )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




CREATE TABLE OrderItem(
      OrderItemID    int  PRIMARY KEY,
      ProductID      int NOT NULL,
      OrderID        int NOT NULL,
      Quantity       int NOT NULL,
      PricePerUnit   double NOT NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product(
       ProductID            int PRIMARY KEY,
       ProductName          varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
       ProductDescription   varchar(100)  NOT NULL,
       SerialNumber         int NOT NULL,
       UnitesInStock        int  NOT NULL,
       UnitsOnOrder         int NOT NULL,
       UnitPrice            double NOT NULL,
       SupplierID           int not NULL
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SupplySchedule(
       ShippingID        int PRIMARY KEY,
       ShippingMode      varchar(50) NOT NULL

)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Supplier(
        SupplierID       int PRIMARY KEY,
        SupplierName     varchar(40) NOT NULL,
        SupplierAddress  varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        ContactName      varchar(128) NOT NULL


   )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Odd question. Homework? Note that price would NEVER be DOUBLE

Comment: Its part of a project and I cant follow any explanations ir videos anywhere

Comment: We can determine a customer's name from their unique customer_id. This is a functional dependency. The reverse cannot be said to be true, because two customers can have the same name.